# Convert excel formula for LEN, SEARCH, SUBSTITUTE into SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, excel-formula

The existing row on the left is in SQL, I want to create a table inside of SQL applying the following excel formula to it:

I'm trying to apply a formula grabbing text to the right of the last dash in column 'PO#'

```
**=IFERROR(RIGHT([@[PO'#]],LEN([@[PO'#]])-SEARCH("$",SUBSTITUTE([@[PO'#]],"-","$",LEN([@[PO'#]])-LEN(SUBSTITUTE([@[PO'#]],"-",""))))), [@[PO'#]])**
```

[Normalized output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsVPy.png)

Comment: SQL isn't Excel. What is this formula supposed to do? What does the table look like, what is the input and what is the expected output?

Comment: You need to break down what that formula does then re-create it.

Comment: Post what you want as *text*, not links to images. In any case, SQL is *not* a text manipulation language. If you want to clean up text you should do so when loading the data into the database, not try to do this afterwards

Comment: Just grab all characters to the last dash of column PO#

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;). All within the question, no images.

Answer (score 1):

Why not something like this ... Note the "*Fail-Safe*" `...+'-'`

```
Select right(SomeCol,charindex('-',reverse(SomeCol)+'-')-1)
```

Comment: Good answer, +1 from my side!

Comment: A better failsafe would be `Select right(SomeCol, nullif(charindex('-', reverse(SomeCol)), 0))`

Comment: @Charlieface not sure I'd agree better, but certainly viable.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution based on *tokenization*.

Method #2 as an alternative method.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens VARCHAR(1000));
INSERT INTO @tbl (tokens) VALUES 
('1333-fd-fdd'),
('12345'),
('BRASIL'),
('1122-18-fdl'),
('1122-18-fia');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = '-';

-- Method #1
SELECT t.*
   , c.value('(/root/r[last()]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Result
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
      REPLACE(tokens, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
      ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c);

-- Method #2
SELECT t.* --, pos
   , RIGHT(tokens, pos) AS Result
FROM @tbl AS t
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX(@separator, REVERSE(tokens)) - 1) AS t1(_pos)
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT IIF(_pos = -1, LEN(tokens), _pos)) AS t2(pos);
```

**Output**

| ID | tokens | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1333-fd-fdd | fdd |
| 2 | 12345 | 12345 |
| 3 | BRASIL | BRASIL |
| 4 | 1122-18-fdl | fdl |
| 5 | 1122-18-fia | fia |

Comment: I usually love your XML solutions, but this seems like a long way to go :)

Comment: You know what we will be asked next: "Oops, I made a mistake. I need a token one before last one". Tokenization always beats string parsing, specially with the power of XQuery.